# How do you take away the underline from an anchor element?

Tags: html, css, anchor, underline

I have tried `text-decoration:none !important;` but it won't work. Here is my code:

```css
.no {
  text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

```html
<a href="fmab-no.html" class="no">No, Different</a>
```

It works here but does not work for my VS code. Is this a bug?

Comment: As you say, it works in your snippet. Without more details, it's impossible to know what the issue could be (bad CSS link path, caching, other interfering CSS, etc.)

Comment: _"It works here but does not work for my VS code. Is this a bug?"_ VSC doesn't render HTML, so how are you viewing the result?

Comment: i am using an extension to view it as a live server @j08691

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some notes:

- you can use `>` css selector to give higher priority to the element. for example:

`.parent-class > .no { text-decoration:none !important; }`

- if you work with frameworks like `react`,`vue` or `angular`, it may be due to the encapsulation feature.
- If the code was written by someone else, it may have used the `:before` or `:after` feature in css to create the underline.